# xauth time out in locking file /root/.Xauthority

Tags: php, apache, fedora, xserver

can someone help me get rid of this error

```
xauth:  timeout in locking authority file /root/.Xauthority
```

when i try to execute this command

```
xvfb-run -f /root/.Xauthority -e /var/www/html/cove/mm3103/tmp/Coder_afbb521946dad4bdf2dac3e3a7b03dee/media/Xerr.txt -s "-screen 0 324x296x16" flashplayer "http://localhost/cove/mm3103/moviemasher/com/moviemasher/core/MovieMasher/stable.swf?base=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fcove%2Fmm3103%2Fexample%2Fserver&policy=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fcove%2Fcrossdomain.xml&debug=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fcove%2Fmm3103%2Ferror%2F%3Fpath%3DCoder_afbb521946dad4bdf2dac3e3a7b03dee%2Fmedia%2F&config=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fcove%2Fmm3103%2Ftmp%2Fcache%2Fcd11b04261281649ea1ab5491fde2fb8.xml"
```

via a php cgi script

thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

delete /root/.Xauthority file and recall command

Comment: If that does not work, check your /var/log/audit/audit.log, selinux may be preventing access  (probably need to fix dir with restorecon)